# IIS 7.0 redirecting https to http

Tags: iis-7, https

We have a main address which example1.example.com and we have a Https certificate issued for this address. But the main code is on example2.example.com and we used to redirect the first one to this one.
Now we want to use https and I want to know if it's possible for us to do so. We don't have any https certificate on the 2nd server.

Comment: Are you sending them to the pages on example2, so they will leave example1? Are you using ASP.NET or some other framework?

Comment: Yes, there is no code o example1.example.com so they would work on pages on example2.example.com.

Answer (score 1):

For me the best and easiest method on IIS 7.x to do redirection is with the URL Rewite module of Microsoft:

- to find [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)
- and many different configuration examples for it, [here](http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/#more-307)

Answer (score 0):

In Global.asax I have this block:

```
        if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"] != "on")
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"), true);
            return;
        }
```

This turns http requests into https, which you will want to do on example1, if example2 refers back to example1.

For what you want to do, this should work:

```
        if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"] == "on")
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("https://", "http://"), true);
            return;
        }
```